# class of data frame column data changed unintentionally- leading to downstream NA values

Tags: r, class, dataframe

I have read a set of data from an excel file into a variable "proportions". I tested the results of read.xls (package-gdata), read.xlsx (package-xlsx) and XLConnect (but this made no difference).

I need to analyse the column number 27 of the proportions variable.

```
 > class(proportions$X.27)
 [1] "character"
```

You can see that the class of that column is initially a character.

My problem is that when I go to subset the data in a particular way into a variable called "proportions1", the column classes are perturbed...

```
 proportions1<-data.frame(proportions$X.5, proportions$Lab.data, proportions$X.26, proportions$X.27, proportions$X.28, proportions$X.29, proportions$X.30)
 > class(proportions1$X.27)
 [1] "NULL"
```

When I reset the colnames to things that make sense it changes the columns' class to "factor"

```
 > colnames(proportions) <- c("barcode1", "WBC", "Neutrophils", "Lymphocytes", "Eosinophils", "Monocytes", "Basophils")
 > class(proportions1$Neutrophils)
 [1] "factor"
```

Later down the line I have to convert these column values to numerics such that I can plot them. I do this using:

```
     as.numeric(as.character(proportions1$Neutrophils)) etc.
```

However this leads to a loss of as much as 90% of my data (varyingly across the different analysed columns i.e. in some of my columns I lose 10% while in others 90% of the values).

When I contrast the data of proportions to the final data of :

```
 head(proportions$X.27)
 [1]  "10.8"            "5.3"             "3.9"            "2.8" ......
```

So according to the following error (note the values have been rearranged):

```
 > head(as.numeric(as.character(proportions1$Neutrophils)))
 [1]   NA   NA  2.3 14.9   NA   NA
 Warning message:
 In head(as.numeric(as.character(proportions1$Neutrophils))) :
   NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is there something that I can do to mitigate the NA values?

Comment: from the raw data: > dput(head(proportions[,"X.26"]))
c("abs neutrophils", "", "10.8", "5.3", "3.9", "2.8")

Comment: Use `dput(head(proportions))` and paste the output in your question